# Outlook 2010 reminders keep popping up even if closed

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar, events, reminder

Today when I got to work and started my computers I got a event reminder for my last events last friday. I closed the reminder, but perhaps 10 minutes later it pops up again, and another 10 minutes later it popped up yet again. As the day is passing all my reminders for this day is added to the list of reminders that keep popping up 10 minutes after that they are closed.

I've tried both the repair function in Windows Control Panel --> E-mail and the scanpst.exe program, but none of them solved the problem. I've tried `outlook.exe /cleansniff` and `outlook.exe /cleanreminders`, but that didn't help either.

Reading on the net there seem to be some reports with this for reoccuring calendar events, but my affected events are one-timers.

How can I get the closed reminders to stay closed?

Update: I noticed that I have 282 drafts of the meetings that I keep getting reminders of.

Comment: [This Microsoft TechNet article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/outlook/thread/76aefaaa-6e96-477d-b66d-cd7e7b5aca60/) suggests that this problem has to do with one or more Mac devices syncing the calendar. Will look into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned off calendar syncronization on all Mountain Lion Macs, and the problem stopped. Re-enabled and the problem came back. Turned it off again and will let it stay that way unil Apple posts an update to Mountain Lion.